# MySQL or NoSQL? Recommended way of dealing with large amount of data

Tags: mysql, database, storage

I have a database of which will be used by a large amount of users to store random long string (up to 100 characters). The table columns will be: userid, stringid and the actual long string.

So it will look pretty much like this:

[image]

Userid will be unique and stringid will be unique for each user.

The app is like a simple todo-list app, so each user will have an average amount of 50 todo's.
I am using the stringid in order that users will be able to delete the specific task at any given time.

I assume this todo app could end up with 7 million tasks in 3 years time and that scares me of using MySQL.

So my question is if **this is the actual recommended way of dealing with large amount of data** with long string (every new task gets a new row)? and **is MySQL is the right database solution to choose for this kind of projects ?**

I have not experienced with large amount of data yet and I am trying to save myself for the far future.

Comment: I don't think 2 million is an unusually large number of rows for MySQL.

Comment: The figures given are estimate. Or maybe I should say 7 million.

Comment: 7 mio isn't "large amounts of data", either , especially over a couple of years. I think you underestimate what databases can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty straightforward relational use case.  I wouldn't see a need for NoSQL here.

The table you present should work fine however, I personally would question the need for the compound primary key as you would present this.  I would probably have a primary key on stringid only to enforce uniqueness across all records. Rather than a compound primary key across userid and stringid.  I would then put a regular index on userid.

The reason for this is in case you just want to query by stringid only (i.e. for deletes or updates), you are not tied into always having to query across both field to leverage your index (or adding having to add individual indexes on stringid and userid to enable querying by each field, which means my space in memory and disk taken up by indexes).

As far as whether MySQL is the right solution, this would really be for you to determine.  I would say that MySQL should have no problem handling tables with 2 million rows and 2 indexes on two integer id fields.  This is assuming you have allocated enough memory to hold these indexes in memory.  There is certainly a ton of information available on working with MySQL, so if you are just trying to learn, it would likely be a good choice.

Comment: What if the app goes "boom" and hits 1 million users for example. If 1 million users hit 50 tasks, thats 50 million different rows. Isn't there a performance issue for MySQL to search for all tasks of a specific userid every time he logs in?

Comment: Not if you have proper indexes (indices?), plus why do you think nosql would be faster ?

Comment: @ClydeM That is what indexes are for. Using a NoSQL solution won't prevent you from needing to query for the user's records, those document stores use indexes too.

Comment: @ClydeM  I have had MySQL tables with hundreds of millions of rows.  The bottom line for you is that this would be a good problem for you to have and might require you to radically change your DB architecture (i.e. add server replication, upgrade hardware, etc.).  I wouldn't necessarily worry about thinking about way off "what if" scenarios when you are starting out.  Perhaps set up your service around what you can reasonably expect traffic-wise over the next year or so.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a question of "large amounts" of data (mysql handles large amounts of data just fine and 2 mio rows isn't "large amounts" in any case).

MySql is a relational database. So if you have data that can be normalized, that is distributed among a number of tables that ensures every datapoint is saved only once then you should use MySql (or Maria, or any other relational database).

If you have schema-less data and speed is more important than consistency than you can/should use some NoSql database. Personally I don't see how a todo list would profit from NoSql (doesn't really matter in this case, but I guess as of now most programmig frameworks have better support for relational databases than for Nosql).

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of what you consider a "large amount of data", modern DB engines are designed to handle a lot. The question of "Relational or NoSQL?" isn't about which option can support more data. Different relational and NoSQL solutions will handle the large amounts of data differently, some better than others.

MySQL can handle many millions of records, SQLite can not (at least not as effectively). Mongo (NoSQL) attempts to hold it's collections in memory (as well as the file system) so I have seen it fail with less than 1 million records on servers with limited memory, although it offers sharding which can help it scale more effectively.

The bottom line is: The number of records you store should not play into SQL vs NoSQL decisions, that decision should be left to how you will save and retrieve the data. It sounds like your data is already normalized (e.g. UserID) and if you also desire consistency when you i.e. delete a user (the TODO items also get deleted) then I would suggest using a SQL solution.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that all queries will reference a specific userid. I also assume that the stringid is a dummy value used internally instead of the actual task-text (your random string).

Use an InnoDB table with a compound primary key on `{userid, stringid}` and you will have all the performance you need, due to the way a clustered index works.